# Fresh OpenEMM installation shows bean errors on some pages

Tags: java, deployment, resin, gentoo

We have deployed a fresh openemm installation on a resin server (which wasn't exactly straight forward due to an enormous amount of dependencies although resin is the recommended and default application server). This is our setup:

- latest Gentoo GNU/Linux
- OpenEMM 5.1.1 (compiled from source, including a huge amount of dependent jars)
- Resin 3.2.1 on 127.0.0.1:8080
- Squid Frontend in accelerator mode forwarding traffic to 127.0.0.1:8080

This setup seems to work fine. Almost all pages of OpenEMM work. But the "Actions" menu item throws the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No bean found under attribute key emmaction
```

The other menu item which throws an error is the "Recipients / Overview" menu item:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Missing message for key "gender..short"
```

I'm a pretty noob on java deployments. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:** I already made some progress on this issue. All these problems seem to arise because some variables are interpolated but contain empty values, eg ${recipient.gender} resolves to an empty value and thus tries to lookup gender..short (resolved from "gender.${recipient.gender}.short"). Here's the code snippet:

```
<display:column class="name" headerClass="head_name" titleKey="Salutation">
  <bean:message key="gender.${recipient.gender}.short"/>
</display:column>
```

This is wrapped by a "display:table" like so:

```
<display:table class="dataTable" pagesize="${recipientForm.numberofRows}"
  id="recipient" name="recipientList" sort="external"
  requestURI="/recipient.do?action=${ACTION_LIST}" excludedParams="*"
  partialList="true" size="${recipientList.fullListSize}"
>
```

Any clues where to do further debugging? I already downgraded the displaytag library from 1.2 to 1.1.1 in the hope this would fix the wrong behaviour - but that seemed to be the wrong point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally solved this by downgrading resin from 3.1.x to resin 3.0.x... There seem to be incompatible changes in some of resin's libraries and webapp support code. Which these are and how to fix it to work with the latest resin version however still remains as a mysterium to me.